# Javascript function inside another function a new instance created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to figure out whether `express.Router()` returns a new instance of a router or not. So when reading code I run into this basic JavaScript question.

**./router/index.j**

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  options = options || {}; 

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  router.__proto__ = proto;

  router.params = {}; 
  router._params = []; 
  router.caseSensitive = options.caseSensitive;
  router.strict = options.strict;
  router.stack = []; 

  return router;
};
```

Any time when the outer function is executed (I think it's so via express.Router()), is a new inner function getting created? I believe if it's var router = function(...){...} then it is. But I'm not sure about this case.

Comment: Yes, it does create a closure in the same way as a function expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it creates a new function object every time

function declaration is effectively the same as a named function expression that is hoisted:

```
function f() {

}
```

vs

```
var f = function f() {}; // + hoisting
```